# Using http forms and getting data from web by selenium or standard HTTP post get in c#?

Tags: c#, forms, request, web

I did not know how to name my topic.
My plan is to get from web, some data.
Some data return from submiting values into form. And that form is on the web.

I wonder, what would be faster:

by using selenium for c#

by using standard functions in c#

by using html agility pack

My aim is to get very fast data and many times in minute.
Can anybody give me any suggestion, which one would be the best?

PS. please correct my English, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably make something that is reasonanly fast in C#, at least faster than using Selenium. Use HTML Agility Pack to avoid reinventing the wheel.

However, somethings might be easier to do in Selenium, since it accurately replicates a real user.